# local variable 'location' referenced before assignment-text adventure

Tags: python

I am working on a text adventure as my first python project. I am using a template, (coping code from youtube tutorial). but instead of creating a game loop, I want it to be a function, to be executed when the player types in a command. (that part is working).
Here is the code from the tutorial:

## Text_Adventure

```
bridge = ("Bridge", "You are on the bridge of a spaceship, sitting in the captains chair. ")

readyRoom = ("Ready Room" , "The captains ready room ")

lift = ("Lift" , "A turbolift that takes you throughout the ship. ")

transitions = {
    bridge: (readyRoom, lift),
    readyRoom: (bridge,),
    lift: (bridge,)
    }
 
 

location = bridge


while True:

    print (location[1])
    print ("You can go to these places: ")

    for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
        print (i + 1, t[0])
    
    choice = int(input('Choose one: '))
    location = transitions[location][choice - 1]
```

That part works okay, but when I try to turn it into a function:

## Text_Adventure

```
bridge = ("Bridge", "You are on the bridge of a spaceship, sitting in the captains chair. ")

readyRoom = ("Ready Room" , "The captains ready room ")

lift = ("Lift" , "A turbolift that takes you throughout the ship. ")

transitions = {
    bridge: (readyRoom, lift),
    readyRoom: (bridge,),
    lift: (bridge,)
    }
 
 

location = bridge


def travel():

    print (location[1])
    print ("You can go to these places: ")

    for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
        print (i + 1, t[0])
    
    choice = int(input('Choose one: '))
    location = transitions[location][choice - 1]

travel()
```

I get the error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'location' referenced before assignment
```

I know that the best way to learn something is by finding the answer yourself. I have been searching for awhile now and am not getting anywhere, Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Kenneth\My Documents\Python_Projects\projects\TA.Project\location\places_simple.py", line 28, in <module>
    travel()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Kenneth\My Documents\Python_Projects\projects\TA.Project\location\places_simple.py", line 19, in traveling
    print (location[1])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'location' referenced before assignment
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified quite a bit:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> def foo():
...    print a
...    a = 3
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

## What's happening

When python sees `a` the first time in the function, it is a non-local variable (in this case, a global).  The second time though, since you're assigning to it, python thinks it is a local variable -- But the name is already taken by a global variable which leads to the error.

There are a few workarounds -- You can declare `a` as `global` so that python will know that when you say `a = 3`, you mean that the `global` variable `a` is 3.  Personally though, I would advise you beat on the code some more so that you no longer need a global variable.  99 times out of 100, if you're using `global`, there's probably a better way to refactor the code so you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write to a global variable you should use `global` to declare it.
instead this:

```
def travel():
```

put this:

```
def travel():
    global location
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, I dont think Ill keep it like this, but it works for now:

```
#Simplefied version:
a = 1
def foo():
    global a
    a = 3
    print a 
def getFoo():
    print a
print "foo results: "
foo()
print "getFoo results: "
getFoo()
```

Prints:

```
foo results: 
3
getFoo results: 
3
```

I was having trouble calling "a" from another function, that's why I displayed the function and the result separately. Its working for now, Thank You